# When we call a solidity function via web3js , how does the code flows along with data formats during all the process

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

When we call a solidity function via web3js, how does the code flows along with data formats during all the process?

For example, if I call a solidity function through web3js, how does it get executed. Can anyone explain the complete flow?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend taking the time to read [How does Ethereum work, anyway?](https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369)

But for now, a short explanation

1. When you call a method on a contract through `web3.js`, the library
   will encode your method call as `data` attribute on the transaction.
   [Here's a good explanation about ethereum transactions and data
   attribute](https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f)
2. The ethereum node your `web3.js` is connected to will receive your transactions and do some basic checks of `nonce` and `balance`
3. Once the basic checks pass, the node will *broadcast* the transaction to the rest of the network
4. When a network node receives a transaction with `data` attribute, it will execute the transaction using the Ethereum EVM. The outcome
   of the transaction is modified state of the contract storage. [More
   about contract storage](https://medium.com/aigang-network/how-to-read-ethereum-contract-storage-44252c8af925)
5. The expectation is that the transaction will produce the *same* state change on every single node in the network. This is how
   consensus is reached and the transaction (and the contract state
   change) become part of the canonical chain (mined and not belonging
   to an uncle block)